# DataGridView not showing all columns from table

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am currently creating a DataGridView within visual studio. The whole process is working fine and I have no errors. Apart from only one column is shown when executed when hitting 'Start' and is shown within a form.

For example in my process, only the "total cost" column is shown in the "bookingID" row in my DataGridView. I want all three columns to show, as in the code below states. The three rows are "bookingID", "paymentConfirmation" and "totalCost".

Here is the code:

```
     Imports System.Data.Sql
     Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Form4
Dim SQL As New SQLControl
Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection



Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With DGVData

        .Rows.Clear()
        .ColumnCount = 3


        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Booking ID"
        .Columns(0).Width = 75
        .Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter


        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Payment Confirmation"
        .Columns(1).Width = 100
        .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Total Cost"
        .Columns(2).Width = 100
        .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter



    End With

    LoadBookingData()
End Sub
Public Sub LoadBookingData()
    Dim loadSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM booking"
    Dim RowsCount As Integer


    If SQL.SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

        SQL.RunQuery(loadSQL)

        RowsCount = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count

        MsgBox(RowsCount)
        ' there are records !
        DGVData.Rows.Add(RowsCount)
        For i As Integer = 0 To RowsCount - 1
            With DGVData
                .Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("bookingID")
                .Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("paymentConfirmation")
                .Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("totalCost")
            End With
        Next

    Else

        MsgBox("There is no records", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Sorry")
        SQL.SQLDS.Reset()
        SQL.SQLCon.Close()
    End If

        SQL.SQLDA.Fill(SQL.SQLDS, "GettingInfo")
        RowsCount = SQL.SQLDS.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows.Count
        If RowsCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox("There is no records", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Sorry")
            SQL.SQLDS.Reset()
            SQL.SQLCon.Close()
        Else
            ' there are records !
            DGVData.Rows.Add(RowsCount)
            For i As Integer = 0 To RowsCount - 1
                With DGVData
                .Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = SQL.SQLDS.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows(i).Item("bookingID")
                .Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = SQL.SQLDS.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows(i).Item("paymentConfirmation")
                .Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = SQL.SQLDS.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows(i).Item("totalCost")
                End With
            Next
        End If
        SQL.SQLDS.Reset()
        SQL.SQLCon.Close()
End Sub
```

Here is the query within SQLControl:

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Public Class SQLControl
Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data Source=JENNIFER\DDAP2015;Initial Catalog=zachtravelagency;Integrated Security=True;"}
Public SQLcmd As SqlCommand
Public SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter
Public SQLDS As DataSet



Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()

        SQLCon.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return False
End Function

Public Sub RunQuery(Query As String)
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()

        ' CREATE COMMAND
        SQLcmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)

        ' FILL DATASET
        SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd)
        SQLDS = New DataSet
        SQLDA.Fill(SQLDS)


        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

        ' MAKE SURE CONNECTION IS CLOSED
        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQLCon.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

An example in code on how to fix this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to post row by row to the DGV - in fact it is a bad idea when there are thousands of rows.  Bind the DGV to the table you fill instead.  It would also appear that `SQLControl` type is misusing DBObject as possibly leaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to sort through all the capabilities of .Net to figure out which ones to use. You are writing a lot of code that could be moved to a library.

Here are two Functions() that have saved me a lot of time:

```
Function GetDataTable(ByVal SQL As String, Optional ByVal ConnectString As String = "", Optional ByVal SingleRow As Boolean = False) As DataTable ' returns read only Datatable
    Try
        If ConnectString.Length = 0 Then ConnectString = g.OISConnectString
        Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectString)
            Dim rdr As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, con)
            If SingleRow Then
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow Or CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Else
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            End If
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(rdr)
            rdr.Close()
            Return dt
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExpLog.LogMsgBox(ex, ex.Message, , "GetDataTable", "SQL: " & SQL)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
Function GetDataView(ByVal SQL As String, Optional ByVal ConnectString As String = "") As DataView ' returns read only Dataview
    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = GetDataTable(SQL, ConnectString)
        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
            Return dv
        End If
    Catch ex2 As NullReferenceException
        Return Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExpLog.LogMsgBox(ex, ex.Message, , "GetDataView", "SQL: " & SQL)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

GetDataTable returns a read-only table that loads more quickly than a full featured table. The table can be used as the RecordSource for a DataGridView.

Sometimes I use GetDateView when I what to use the filter capability with the DataGridView. Just use the returned DataView as the record source and then you can set the DataView filter to control what is shown in the grid.